# How to stop someone that has cloned my WordPress blog

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

My WordPress blog is completely cloned. That clone site is updating in real time with my blog. I am surprised that someone can actually do that.

What should I do to stop harmful impact in my search engine ranking? Is there any way to tell Google not to index that site?

How do I stop this?

Comment: When you say in real time, it doesn't sound right to me unless someone got access. Is the impact is immediate?

Comment: It usually means somebody has a proxy server doing the cloning.

Comment: Or they are pointing their domain name to a sites IP address when the site is the only site configured on the server.

Comment: At least use the canonical tag on each page pointing to the page on your own site using a full URL. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en As well, consider using links with full URLs to your pages on your site.

Comment: Examine your access logs - can you identify the IP address of the cloned site (ie. _proxy server_, as Stephen suggests) that is making these requests?